# how to add elements to HashMap whose key is Integer and value is arraylist in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, arraylist, hashmap

I am a writing a class that whose constructor takes an `List<String>` and returns a hashmap having length of string as `key(Integer)` and its value as `arrayList<String>` that holds string.
That is I am trying to map length of strings to list of strings. Here is my code.

```
public class Solver {
   Map<Integer,ArrayList<String>> inventoryMap;

    //constructor
    public Solver(List<String> list){
    inventoryMap=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();
    for (String s : list) {
         int x = s.length();
         if (inventoryMap.containsKey(x)){
            inventoryMap.put(x,inventoryMap.get(x).add(s));
         } else {
            newlist=new ArrayList<String>();
            newlist.add(s);
            inventoryMap.put(x,newlist);
         }
      }
   }
```

when I complile this code, I get the following error

```
Solver.java:12: put(java.lang.Integer,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>) in java.util.Map<java.lang.Integer,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>> cannot be applied to (int,boolean)
            inventoryMap.put(x,inventoryMap.get(x).add(s));
```

I think I am going wrong in adding `String elements` to `my ArrayList<String>` which is `value` of Map
can you guide me with what I could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: Check the JavaDocs for `ArrayList.add()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (inventoryMap.containsKey(x)) {
     inventoryMap.put(x,inventoryMap.get(x).add(s));
}
```

Change this with

```
if (inventoryMap.containsKey(x)) {
    inventoryMap.get(x).add(s);
}
```

Reason is `inventoryMap.get(x).add(s)` will return boolean so you cann't put boolean in place of List.

As map already contains list so adding any element in a list you need not to put any entry in a map. Just get the list from map and add element to it.

Answer (score 1):

inventoryMap.get(x).add(s) returns boolean and you tried to put it in the map. This is the cause of the exception. Put the list in the map will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code inventoryMap.get(x).add(s) adds the value to the list and return a boolean.
So You need to have something like.

```
List<String> list =inventoryMap.get(x);
list.add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot chain your method calls like `inventoryMap.put(x,inventoryMap.get(x).add(s))` since [`add` returns a `boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29). As a matter of fact, you don't even need the `put` statement. Since you aren't `remove`ing the `List`, its reference will stay in the `Map` so any updates to the `List` will be  visible.

All you need is `inventoryMap.get(x).add(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `inventoryMap.get(x).add(s)` returns `boolean`(whether elements where successfully added or not ). So is incompatible with the type `ArrayList<String>`. You can simple do

```
inventoryMap.get(x).add(s)
```

No need to explicitly call pur() function.

Secondly `int x = s.length();` should be `Integer x = s.length();`. You can put int where Integer is expected(anyways you cannot use int in generics).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this line

```
        inventoryMap.put(x,inventoryMap.get(x).add(s));
```

is that `inventoryMap.get(x).add(s)` will return a `boolean` and map expects a `List` here. You need to break down this statement. something like this:

```
List<String> stirngsList = inventoryMap.get(x);
stirngsList.add(s);
```